# Djanogo swagger https

Tags: python, django, swagger

Используя связку django который работает на nginx. Пытаюсь подключить https, собственно это мне удалось, сайт доступен по протоколу https но вот свагер по дефолту отправляет запросы на http, что приводит с неудачной попытке отправки запроса. в интернете пишут, что необходимо добавить такие строчки в файл settings.py

```
SE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Что собственно я и сделал, но это не дало положительного результата. Подскажите как можно решить данный вопрос?

Comment: догадка: может в nginx настройки по портам посмотреть? Если "что то" отправляет запрос на 80 порт, обработать это "что-то" в nginx.

Comment: Просто когда свагер формирует curl команду, она там http. Я так понимаю можно как то сдлеать что бы свагер знал, что сайт работает по https протоколу